# Sending multiple parameters to javascript from a HTML form button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

Ok so i have a form that has three input boxes, at the moment they're text, but they will be changed to password. When the submit button is pressed i want the for to send the form data to an Ajax script.

I have this working with just one parameter the button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" 
    onClick="return pass(this.form.oldPass.value;">
```

Now i've tried adding the 'this.form' part three times because thats how many parameters the function would take but it just doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" 
    onClick="return pass(this.form.oldPass.value,
                         this.form.newPass.value, 
                         this.form.newPassCheck);">
```

Is this the right way to go about passing form data to a script? is there another way around it or am i just doing something wrong here?

thanks for the help, if you need anymore code i'll add it.

Comment: Please show `function pass` and do not call code onclick of a submit button. Instead call it onsubmit of the form - and preferably added onload via a script in the head. If you do NOT need to submit the form, then you need to return false in the onsubmit event

Comment: With jQuery, you just need to do a `$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one. (you need [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to do this.)

```
<form>
 old pass <input type="password" id="old_pass" />
 new pass <input type="password" id="new_pass" />
 new pass confirmation <input type="password" id="new_pass_confirm"/>
</form>
```

in your .js file , write this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var old_pass = $('#old_pass').val();
    var new_pass = $('#new_pass').val();
    var new_pass_confirm = $('#new_pass_confirm').val();

    //then call your method with those vars as parameter
    anyMethod(old_pass, new_pass, new_pass_confirm);

});

//this is your function
function anyMethod(old_pass, new_pass, new_pass_confirm)
{
  //put your validation code or ajax call here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add **id** for each of your input boxes and you can get value in function, like:

```
function pass() {
 var old = document.getElementById("yourOldPassId").value;
 var new = document.getElementById("yourNewPassId").value;
 var newConfirm  = document.getElementById("yourNewConfirmPassId").value;
}
```

Did you mean something like this

Answer (score 2):

Give the inputs some ids and get the data from there.

Something like:

```
<input type bla bla id="whateverId0" />
```

For each input.

The submit should have something like onclick="whateverFunction()"

The js should look like:

```
     function whateverFunction()
     {
          val0 = document.getElementById('whateverId0');
          // For all 3 values.

          // Do whatever you want with them.
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should add an onSubmit listener to your form. There are good js frameworks out there like jquery which are easy to use. That way you can make a listener which runs a function when you submit your form. In that function you can extract the data to json for example and ajax it to your server.

[info about jquery](http://jquery.com/)

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[how to extract form data](http://www.guyford.co.uk/index.php/forum/17-jquery/47-jquery-extracting-form-data)